Add row to tbl_summary
I am creating a summary table of my dataframe data2. There is a column called Group which I am summarising my data by.
Function:
data2 %>% 
  tbl_summary(by=Group)

data2 is a subset of data1. I want to add a row to the summary table which states the percentage that each group is of the larger dataset. These percentages would be calculated as:
GroupA <- (sum(data2$Group == "GroupA")/nrow(data1))*100
GroupB <- (sum(data2$Group == "GroupB")/nrow(data1))*100
GroupC <- (sum(data2$Group == "GroupC")/nrow(data1))*100
GroupD <- (sum(data2$Group == "GroupD")/nrow(data1))*100

How can I add these values to my summary table?
My table currently looks like:



Characteristic
GroupA, N = 24
GroupB, N = 26
GroupC, N = 27
GroupD, N = 49




Age
84 (76, 90)
91 (88, 97)
75 (68, 86)
90 (85, 96)


Female
9 (38%)
18 (69%)
10 (37%)
22 (45%)



I want my table to look like:



Characteristic
GroupA, N = 24
GroupB, N = 26
GroupC, N = 27
GroupD, N = 49




Age
84 (76, 90)
91 (88, 97)
75 (68, 86)
90 (85, 96)


Female
9 (38%)
18 (69%)
10 (37%)
22 (45%)


% of total
5%
5.2%
6%
10.1%



Some sample data:
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   Group  Female   Age
   <chr>  <lgl>  <dbl>
 1 GroupC TRUE      97
 2 GroupD FALSE     96
 3 GroupD TRUE      74
 4 GroupA TRUE     102
 5 GroupA FALSE     68
 6 GroupB FALSE     92
 7 GroupA FALSE    100
 8 GroupD TRUE      89
 9 GroupB TRUE     102
10 GroupB FALSE     92
11 GroupA TRUE      85
12 GroupD TRUE      64
13 GroupC FALSE     89
14 GroupB TRUE      84
15 GroupC FALSE     88

I tried playing with add_stat function, but it seems this only adds columns, not rows.

Could we have a minimal example of your data? You could provide this by using dput(data2[sample(seq_along(nrow(data2)), 15),  ])

Sure! I've added some sample data to the post.
